# I need help to make a legislature

Tags: politics, government

The imaginary country has 5 provinces. The 3 most populous provinces have 10 million inhabitants each and their area is 500 000 square kilometers. The other 2 provinces have 500 000 inhabitants and their area is 1 million square kilometers. It is not possible to redivide the provinces because of geographical and ethnic differences.

The first issue is the number of congressmen

If we had 1 representative for each 250 000 inhabitants, the densely-inhabited provinces would have 40 representative and the sparse provinces 2.
If it were 1 representative for each 1 million, the dense provinces would have 10 and the sparse ones 1. It is weird because, if there were a province of 250 000 inhabitants, a province of 1 490 000 inhabitants and a province of 1 510 000 inhabitants, the first two would have 1 and the third 2.

The second issue is to choose between bicameralism or unicameralism

A bicameral legislature is slow and rambling, but unicameralism may be bad for provinces that have few representatives.
But I have another idea. Instead of having two assemblies, the bicameral system can be simulated with only one assembly. In order to decide something, the decision must pass in two voting criteria. In the first criterion, the vote weight of each representative is the same. In the second criterion, the vote weight of each representative is divided by the number of representatives of their home province and this criterion works like a veto rather than a decision.

Comment: What are the priorities of your system? Quick approval of acts, or fair and balanced representation of both large and small provinces? Without that we cannot come with a preferred option.

Comment: Quick rule of thumb, you need 1 representative per 5,000 people. Much more than that and your representative gets out of touch. Much less, and you have an overcrowded legislature

Comment: You may want to clarify that this is a federation. (Countries can be organized either as federations or as unitary states.) In some countries, a "province" is just a geographical term with no political meaning; in a unitary country such as France or Romania "provinces" are purely geographical and have no political identity; the phrase "a province has more representatives than another" is utterly meaningless -- representatives represent *people* not provinces.

Comment: Hi.  There are lots of approaches you could take, depending on what your goals and priorities are.  On the one hand you could have equal representation across your entire population (ignore the provinces).  On the other hand you could have one representative per province, period.  Or anything in between.  I'm putting your question on hold temporarily; please [edit] to describe your goals, what makes a government "good" for you, and then we can reopen.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

What you're describing is very similar to the [Australian Parliament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliament_of_Australia).

Australia has the lowest average population density in the world, but considering most of the inland territories are desert the vast majority of the population lives on the coastline and in fact the two most populous cities in Australia (Sydney, capital of New South Wales and Melbourne, capital of Victoria) account for around 40% of Australia's population. That means that NSW and Vic have a huge representation in our House of Representatives (lower house), and less populous states and territories have proportionally less representation.

Our Senate (upper house) on the other hand was specifically designed to even that out. 10x seats per state, 2x seats per territory. The idea of having an upper house in this configuration was deliberately so that the more populous states couldn't override the needs of the less populous ones in the lower house; in theory the other states can override the decisions made on equal representation of the people by providing equal representation of the states.

In practice, party based politics override this thinking anyway, and a bicameral parliament is (again, in practice) used by the people as a check and balance at elections, often many vote one party in their electorate, another to the senate so that no side has too much power. This is one of the challenges of a culture that deeply distrusts its politicians, but I digress.

Ultimately, there are 3 questions you need to ask yourself about your mythical country;

1) Do your provinces have their own legislative power and do they require their federal counterparts to consider their interests in any way?

2) Is there any fundamental differences in culture, means, or needs of the provincial citizens by comparison to the urban ones?

3) Do your citizenry have any reason (real or perceived) to mistrust their legislature or believe that their powers should in any way be curtailed?

If the answer to one or more of these questions is YES, then you need a bicameral system. Not want; need. Ultimately, the provinces won't trust a federal system that tramples over any rights they may have. You also don't want to disenfranchise a provincial minority by constantly voting in urban-centric legislation, as this will sew discontent (and possibly revolt) among those who no longer believe they have a voice. Finally, giving a second chamber to your legislative review ensures that the concerns of the people about checks and balances are at least in part assuaged.

Remember that any body that is represented by a body politic will want *equal* representation. For the most part, that means the body of people. In a federal environment, it also means the states (or provinces) and a second house fills that requirement nicely - one house for the people, one for the states.

Answer (score 2):

To be fair the representatives by number of citizens is basically what a some countries have now, each has a vote equal to others, and obviously it has never caused problems before...

Often however, representatives come from 1 per town, soemtimes even a city of 1 million could only have 1 representative at the national level, whereas a city of 50,000 could still have 1. it all depends on how the provinces are laid out.

but at the same time, dependent on what part of the timeline this country is currently in, then these towns might be smaller, or they may decide to keep most governmental decisions provincial, and then only the really big stuff is debated on a national level.

Your 2 low population provinces sound like agricultural provinces whereas the others seem a lot more built up. and this is similar again to what we have today, how often do you see people that live in country disagree with national decisions made by people in the cities that result in comments like "Such a stupid decision, how would they know what its like out here, they spend all their lives in [London, Washington, Paris, etc]"

A Bicameral system would be far better for one but a Unicameral system would be better for the other. the only thing i would say for certain... when has democratic politics ever not been slow and rambling?

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately this depends on what keeps the electorate happy and convinced that they are being represented.  Specifically, to what extent are the folk from populous provinces willing to give the sparse-province folk disproportionately high representation and the sparse-province folk willing to accept that they are an out-voted minority?

Personally, if I was a citizen of a populous province and my representative effectively had only a twentieth of the vote of the guy sitting next to her, I would feel pretty disenfranchised.

Do you need to have the electoral division based on the provinces at all?  It is possible to have the entire country as a single electorate with a multi-seat single transferable vote electoral system.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the electoral college of the US, lol.

Joking aside, it sounds like that's the issue at hand.  The electoral college, and the system you describe, do result in larger populated areas having more representation.  However, it ensures that the larger representation is not oppressively so.  While 2 or 3 larger areas could have the same representation of 10 smaller areas, the combined power of all smaller areas equals or outweighs that of the larger.

This provides a balance between the needs of the many and the needs of the few.

To offset the unequal power of each region, another chamber (the senate in the US) exists with the same number of representatives for each region.  So in one chamber of congress, the legislature, parliament, whatever you want to call it, you have population based representation, and in the other you have region based representation.

In regards to your world...
You can go with unicameralism and choose either of those 2 chambers as the representative body.  Whichever you choose will cause conflict among the more densely populated cities and less densely populated outer regions.  This could be a good thing for your story line and is something to consider.

You can go with bicameralism (your example at the end of a hybrid is still, in essence, bicameralism), which would result in more debate (which could also be a good thing for your story line) but provides less political conflict for your regions.

**My Suggestion ->**

Let the story line decide.  If political discord is a central part of the story, go with unicameralism.  If it's not, go with bicameralism.  Don't try to force the story line into a preconceived block that may end up causing more plot issues than it solves.  More important that deciding which to go with at the moment is ensuring you understand the benefits and drawbacks of both so you can make the right decision for your world when you get to that point in its creation